# Which article is used in this case?

Tags: articles

He arrived on __ train and was ready to put his plan into action.

**1.** The 11.30;

**2.** A 11.30;

**3.** 11.30 the;

**4.** 11.30 a.

Comment: Hmmm.  We can say "He's leaving on the 11:30" but can we say "He *arrived* on the 11:30"?  Is 11:30 the time the train departs from the local station? And is **the 11:30** a reference to the departing train?

Answer (score 3):

1. is the answer that is most likely correct, but there are situations in which 2. may be correct.

> He arrived on the 11:30 train and was ready to put his plan into action.

The definite article is used because we are talking about a specific train. It was not any old train, it was specifically the 11:30 train.

However, if the train arrived at a train station, and

1/ more than one train arrived in the station at 11:30, and

2/ the speaker is not sure which of those trains that 'He" arrived on,

then it is possible that the speaker may say:

> He arrived on an 11:30 train.

Note: In this case we use 'an 11:30 train' not 'a 11:30 train' because 'eleven' starts with a vowel sound.

In standard English the time of the train (or bus, ferry, plane, etc.) is always placed in front of the mode of transport that is arriving.

Answer (score 0):

1: "The 11:30 train". Here's why:

It's a specific train, so it has to be the definite article "the". That eliminates options 2 and 4.

11:30 is here being used as an adjective, and in English adjectives go between an article and the corresponding noun. That means options 3 (and, again, 4) cannot be correct.

There are situations in which one might write "an 11:30 train" (notice that because the next word is "11", which starts with a vowel sound, it has to be "an" rather than "a") but in general that's not idiomatic.

Comment: I don't completely agree that "it's a specific train, so it must be the definite article." If I know what time he arrived, but I am not sure what day he arrived, I could say, "I can't recall the day, but I know he arrived on an 11:30 train." (As you say, that's an unusual case, but it's nevertheless possible.)